# NGINX - Skip redirect to https with proxypass to upstream

Tags: redirect, nginx

As the title says what I would like to do is to keep my configuration intact and just add a /location
the /location needs to be skipped from the $scheme redirection.
In few words the set up is 
redirect everything to upstream
add www
add https (using letsencrypt ssl)
Need to skip the https part for specific location. lets say if i type: www.example.com/location I need to be in http proto.

Thx for any assistance!

The conf:

```
<code>upstream example.com {
    server 1.2.3.4:80;
}
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name example.com;
        return 302 https://www.$host$request_uri;

location / {
        proxy_pass http://example.com;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

}
server{
        listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
        server_name example.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com-0001/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com-0001/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
        return 302 https://www.$host$request_uri;
        ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparam.pem;
        ssl_stapling on;
        ssl_stapling_verify on;
        resolver 1.1.1.1 8.8.8.8;
        resolver_timeout 5s;

        add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;
        add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
        add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
        add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";

        server_tokens off;

location / {
        proxy_pass http://example.com;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}

server {
        listen 80;
        server_name www.example.com;
        return 302 https://$host$request_uri;

location / {
        proxy_pass http://example.com;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

}

server{
        listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
        server_name www.example.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot

        ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparam.pem;
        ssl_stapling on;
        ssl_stapling_verify on;
        resolver1.1.1.1 8.8.8.8;
        resolver_timeout 5s;

        add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;
        add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
        add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
        add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";

        server_tokens off;



location / {
        proxy_pass http://example.com;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }


}
```

Comment: You can't use http and HSTS with a browser. But if you wrap the `return` in a `location /` block, you will be able to define another `location` for your `proxy_pass`.

Comment: Aw! just saw your comment. thx  Ive found a solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So Ive been looking for a solution so I made few tests and fortunately found one.
I'm posting it here ....maybe someone runs on the same problem!

The answer is this:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name www.example.com;
#        return 302 https://$host$request_uri;
location /location {
        proxy_pass http://example.com;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }



location / {
        return 302 https://$host$request_uri;
        proxy_pass http://example.com;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

}
```

So to explain....

Just for the server www.example.com (not for the rest of the above config),
I commented out the 302 redirect.
So far the conf says port 80.
BAM! location */location*
for /location proxy everything back to the upstream.
BAM2 location */* 
For everything else , do a 302 redirect to https then proxy to upstream.

Problem solved.